# How to get list of contents of a particular content type programattically

Tags: theming, nodes

How can i get a list of contents of a particular content type for example "Basic Page". I want basic page title list in a drop down.

I want list of nodes in a drop down and while selecting each will show the content body. How can i do this?

Comment: how do you want to show the content body? by ajax or by jumping?

Comment: We don't have a code writing service here - well gladly help to debug problems with code you've written, so if you run into specific problems during development, please ask about those, ensuring that the code is in the question. Or use Views as betherwisser suggested. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To create a list of content with filters (e.g. by type) you probably want to use either Views or, if you have a reason to load whole entities by ID rather than individual fields, an [EntityFieldQuery](https://www.drupal.org/node/1343708).

Since there may be a large number of nodes, this type of use case usually uses an autocomplete field by entity title rather than a dropdown.

To create a dropdown, you'll want to use the core [Form API](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7) to create a form, and the `#options` array for the dropdown field would be provided by either the View or EntityFieldQuery you create.

Comment: Better exposed filter module will help you and also you need use ajax on in your views

Comment: If they're using a view to create an `#options` list but not using Views to display the list of content itself, there's no need for ajax in the view. It really depends on what they're trying to do with it.